# mongoengine query a list of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I'm running into a classic pitfall, but can't find a good example with mongoengine of what I should be doing.

Using the standard blog example I have something like:

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    author = StringField()
    approved = BooleanField(default=False)

class Post(Document):
    id = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

For a given blog post (with id `some_id`) I just want to load the list of approved comments. I keep accidentally loading all comments if any of the comments for the post are approved, because I'm matching an element of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments are contained with the document then comments will always contain all comments.

Add a property to Post that filters and only returns a list of approved comments eg:

```
@property
def approved_comments(self):
    return [comment for comment in self.comments if comment.approved]
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this in your models:

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    author = StringField()
    approved = BooleanField(default=False)

class Post(Document):
    id = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    comments = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Comment)
```

NOTICE: EmbeddedDocumentListField instead ListField

Then your query in this way

```
comments_approved =  Post.objects.get(pk=post_id).comments.filter(approve=True)
```

I Hope help you!

Comment: Awesome, this should be selected as the answer )

Comment: 'BaseList' object has no attribute 'filter' getting this error

Comment: A version change I guess. This answer was written a long time ago.